# Syslog user in debian 8.8

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I try to install abuseIO on debian 8.8 (Jessie) and during the installation i have to chown a directory to syslog:adm

This use doesn't exist in debian, but in ubuntu exists by default (from install)

What can i do to overcome this?

I think that adding the syslog user manually wont work, or won't work as expected so i didn't do it.

Comment: why not creating the syslog user?

Comment: Care must be taken when adding a 'syslog' user.  It's important that such a user be created as a system user without a home directory and without the ability to login.

Comment: I dont think it is a good idea because this user is probably related to a process (a system log process) and is doing a certain job. If this is not the case i would probably be able to chown to my own user, not this specific

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the portion of the installation instructions that you are referring to:

[abuseIO Installation Instructions](https://docs.abuse.io/en/latest/installation/)

> Do NOT use supervisor AND systemd at the same time.
>
> ```
> cp -vr /opt/abuseio/extra/etc/* /etc/
> mkdir /var/log/abuseio
> chown syslog:adm /var/log/abuseio
> service rsyslog restart
> supervisorctl reread
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> /etc/init.d/supervisor restart
> supervisorctl stop abuseio_queue_collector
> supervisorctl stop abuseio_queue_email_incoming
> supervisorctl stop abuseio_queue_email_outgoing
> ```

The chown command is available on all GNU/Linux systems.  The instructions indicate that you should change the group to 'adm'...

```
$man chown
chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
```

So,

```
chown syslog:adm
```

means that syslog is the owner of the file and adm is the group... which means, depending on the group file permissions that any user in the adm group may manipulate that file.

---

Since I check my own logs, I never really considered the owner of the log files.  Now that I look in my Debian installations, I see that most log files have "root:adm" as owner:group.

So, you should probably assigned the abuseio log file as:

```
chown root:adm /var/log/abuseio
```

which should probably work.